# (*(pucBuf)++) = (unsigned char) (usValue >> 8);

Tags: c

I got this C language code from the client,which is about message encapsulation,but I don't have a good understanding of this code.

Can someone please explain what it's doing?

Comment: So? What's your question? The expression you posted consists of a bunch of very basic operators of C language. What does your C book say about them? Which one do you have trouble understanding?

Answer (score 9):

```
(*(pucBuf)++) = (unsigned char) (usValue >> 8);
```

can be read as:

- get the value of `usValue` and right-shift it 8 bits;
- cast that to an `unsigned char` type;
- store it into the memory location pointed to by the `pubBuf` pointer;
- advance `pucBuf` to point to the next sequential item of its type.

Most likely it's taking the high-order eight bits of a sixteen(-or-more)-bit value and storing that into a memory buffer, within some sort of loop.

Comment: the full code is:#define CW_STORE_U16(pucBuf, usValue)\
{\
    printf("%d\n", usValue);\
    printf("%d\n", (usValue >> 8));\
    (*(pucBuf)++) = (unsigned char) (usValue >> 8);\
    (*(pucBuf)++) = (unsigned char) (usValue);\
}

Comment: @XiaoRun, then that's _exactly_ what it's doing, storing the two halves of a sixteen bit value into the buffer.